# Atom run package command in init whenever a file is opened

Tags: coffeescript, init, atom-editor

I use the remote-sync package and what I want is to auto-download any file as I open it. Using the 'remote-sync:download-file' command should in theory do the trick but I'm not sure how I use this in init.coffee, I have tried the following but nothing happens so I guess I'm doing something wrong:

```
atom.workspace.observeTextEditors (editor) ->
  atom.commands.dispatch(editor, 'remote-sync:download-file')
```

Anyone got any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

`coffeescript
atom.commands.dispatch(atom.views.getView(atom.workspace), 'remote-sync:download-file')`

Work perfect.